# Invalid setup on a non-virtual overridable in vb member: mock => mock[It.IsAny<string>()]

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, mock

Вот такой код:

```
public interface IGate
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface ICommutator
{
    Dictionary<string, IGate> Gates { get; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestGates()
{
    ICommutator mock = new Mock<ICommutator>();
    Mock<ICommutator> instance = mock.Object;
    mock.Setup(c => c.Gates[It.IsAny<string>()].Name).Returns("K1");
}
```

При отладке теста возникает ошибка "Invalid setup on a non-virtual overridable in vb member: mock => mock[It.IsAny()]" в последней строке тестового метода.

Comment: Неужели нельзя использовать стандартный дикчиньори из за невиртуальности индексатора?

Comment: Уточните, какую версию библиотеки для мокирования вы используете. И да, судя по ошибке, вы не можете мокировать индексатор стандартного Dictionary.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще эмулировать индексатор? Просто создайте мок с нужным словарем

Comment: Либо в ICommutator свойство должно иметь тип IDictionary, тогда вы сможете подставить вместо него свою реализацию

Comment: Заменил словарь на его интерфейс, заработало. Спасибо всем.